# Autenticação de Login / JsonObject

Tags: android, api, login

> Tenho um código de get que pega o email e a senha do banco de dados..Mas no getString ele só compara com um termo,como faço pra usar o equals com todos os usuarios do banco e não filtrar pelo ID...Esse é meu codigo :

private class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;
    //private final String mCep;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... String) {

        HttpURLConnection httpCon = null;

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        //  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"No começo de doInbackground....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     //   int id = 1;

        try {

            String urlLogin = "UrlApi";


            URL url = new URL(urlLogin);
            httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


            httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpCon.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Api-Key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            httpCon.setRequestProperty("X-DreamFactory-Session-Token", "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.yWiWTAhyvZgT1ROUDSb4S0Bc1DQFbVbqbMbJ868EfKw");
            httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic  dGhpYWdvLmNhbWFyZ29AZXZvbHV0aW9uaXQuY29tLmJyOmluaWNpYWwyMDE3");



            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpCon.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            httpCon.disconnect();
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());

        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(result);
            System.out.println(json.getString("resource"));

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json.getString("resource"));




            System.out.println("Email : "+ array.getJSONObject(1).getString("email"));
            System.out.println("Password : "+ array.getJSONObject(1).getString("password"));
            System.out.println("email :"+ array.getJSONObject(1.getString("email"));

            String email = array.getJSONObject(1).getString("email");
            String password = array.getJSONObject(1).getString("password");
            if (mEmail.equals(email) && mPassword.equals(password))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("result", result);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Email ou senha inválido(s)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Ola,

voce retornou um JSONArray porem so esta usando o objeto no indice 1 na comparação, tenta desta forma dentro do try:

```
json = new JSONObject(result);
    System.out.println(json.getString("resource"));
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json.getString("resource"));
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println("Email : "+ jsonObj.getString("email"));
        System.out.println("Password : "+ jsonObj.getString("password"));
        System.out.println("email :"+ jsonObj.getString("email"));
        String email = jsonObj.getString("email");
        String password = jsonObj.getString("password");
        if (mEmail.equals(email) && mPassword.equals(password))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("result", result);
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Email ou senha inválido(s)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigada ,ele aparentemente está retornando um erro na linha  "for(JSONObject jsonObj : array){",no array ...foreach not applicable to type 'org.JSONArray',mas obrigada !!

Comment: Ola samara, ajustei o codigo acima.... parece que o JSONArray não trabalha com foreach, como não tenho como testar seu codigo qualquer coisa da um toque;)